# How to Minify Google AdSense JS?

Tags: javascript, smarty, adsense

Whenever I minify the AdSense script I got from Google, it stops working. Any ideas why?

Original Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "xxx";
/* Ad 1 */
google_ad_slot = "2668798369";
google_ad_width = 160;
google_ad_height = 600;
//-->

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
```

Minified Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--google_ad_client = "xxx";/* Ad 1 */google_ad_slot = "2338787596";google_ad_width = 200;google_ad_height = 200;//--></script><script type="text/javascript"src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

The minification is being done by Smarty's `{strip}` tags.

Comment: You probably can't do this as google says you can't change the ads code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the HTML comment tags at the start and end of the first script tag. You don't need them, they're just there to work around Netscape 1.0

Try replacing your minified script with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">google_ad_client="xxx";google_ad_slot="2668798369";google_ad_width=160;google_ad_height=600;</script><script type="text/javascript"src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
```

Comment: still nothing. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

i think you left out this part:

```
//-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `<!--`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Look out for this:

`<!--` and `-->`

Answer (score 0):

It'll be the `<!--` - this can mean 'treat this line as a comment'. It's an old compatibility hack for browers that didn't support JavaScript.

Either remove it or add a linebreak afterwards, i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client="xxx"; ...
```

though I can't see what minifying here is gaining you - there's nothing that can be renamed or compressed.